# "Don't know of" vs. "Don't know"

Tags: meaning

What is the difference between the following?

> I don't know of any other place.
>
> I don't know any other place.

Answer (score 1):

"I don't know of any other place" can mean "I don't know of the existence of any place other than the one of which we both know, and I do (or don't) know anything about the nature of place of which we both know".

"I don't know any other place" can mean "I know of the existence of places other than the one of which we both know, but the one of which we both know is the only one about which I know something of its nature".

In conversation people tend to use these formulations interchangeably and rely on the context for disambiguation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully agree with Eli's base premise (though it is sound), but taking his lead, I would refine it more like:

"I don't know of any other place..." can mean "This is the only place I know about that has this feature, but there could be others, this is just the only one I know of."

versus

"I don't know any other place..." could be interchangeable with the above, or could mean "I know other places don't have this, I checked. Maybe somewhere besides this place has this feature, but so far I haven't found one."

One admits lack of knowledge, the other emphasizes some insight on the complete set of places.

For example:

"I don't know of any other bar that serve fried alligator." suggests you are only aware of one bar that does this, but are clueless if any other bars do it or not.

versus

"I don't know any other bar that serve fried alligator." suggests you love fried alligator, you ask for it at every bar you go to (which is a lot, you drunken cajun), and so far in your search, this bar is the only that does it.

Comment: You couldn't really use either usage without the preceding 'of' or a following 'that'.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know of any other place.

⟹ I do not know *about* any other place. I may know something, but do not know any details to offer an opinion.

> I don't know any other place.

⟹ I do not know any other place at all. This signifies utter lack of knowledge.